# getevent not reporting taps

Tags: adb, touch

I'm trying to automate some tests on a Pixel 5a (Android 13).  To do so, I need to tap on several buttons.  I've been running `adb shell uiautomator dump` to get the pixel locations of the buttons.  However, there's this one button which is clearly visible on the lower right hand corner which the XML dump reports has a location of `(0, 0)`.  That didn't seem right (and running `adb shell input tap 0 0` predictably did nothing) so I ran

```
adb shell getevent -l
```

to see the pixel location as I tapped it manually.  However, no events of any kind were displayed as I tapped all over the screen.  Instead, I saw

```
add device 1: /dev/input/event5
  name:    "uinput-fpc"
add device 2: /dev/input/event4
  name:    "sm7250-bolero-snd-card Button Jack"
add device 3: /dev/input/event3
  name:    "sm7250-bolero-snd-card Headset Jack"
add device 4: /dev/input/event2
  name:    "fts"
add device 5: /dev/input/event1
  name:    "gpio-keys"
add device 6: /dev/input/event0
  name:    "qpnp_pon"
```

My device is rooted and I tried all of this as root as well but got the same output.

Why am I not seeing the screen taps?